# What's the industry standard/typical way to model contango or futures spreads?

Tags: futures, regression, models, spread

If you want to include futures spread either as a response or predictor, I would imagine you also need to include time to expiration somewhere in your model.

What is the industry standard way to factor time into a model or to model futures spreads?  Is it as simple as just including time to expiration as an additional predictor?  Or do people usually normalize spreads in some way.

Thanks